# Does smooth function with compact support have bounded gradient?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, compactness

I am solving problem #18 from chapter 2 Evans (Partial Differential Equations), and the problem gives two smooth functions with compact support, so in order to solve the question I need to have the gradient of one of the functions bounded. I searched but I didn't find any result which shows that smooth function with compact support have bounded gradient.

Comment: The gradient is continuous on a compact set...

Comment: Wow thank you!! I really didn't noticed this... this solves my problem